# How to set CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE from outside CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

## tl;dr

Given a `CMakeList.txt` which I cannot edit, can I set [`CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE.html) to be `STATIC_LIBRARY` while configuring that file?

Ideally I could do this via an environmental variable, but if that is not possible, passing in my value as a command line argument would be ok too.

## Details

I am trying to build a [Conan profile that will allow me to cross build](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/systems_cross_building/cross_building.html) using the [GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm).

Conan provides a mechanism for specifying the compiler binary and compiler + linker flags I would like CMake to use, but I need to specify `set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)` in order for GNU Arm Embedded to pass CMake's compiler check.

In order to get my cross build toolchain to work, then, I am left with 2 options:

1. Every single CMake file that I want to support cross build must check if we are building for an embedded device, and if so, run`set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)`. This is annoying because it forces all projects to have to think about being embedded.
2. OR, Somehow pass `CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE` to CMake without editing the `CMakeList.txt`.

I would like to do 2.

Comment: Preferred method is:  3. Modify **toolchain file**, used for cross-compiling. Probably, this is the only reliable method, because aside from some hardcoded things, toolchain is the only script which is parsed during `try_compile`.

Comment: While the other answers have been helpful, the solution that works best with CMake and Conan together would involve updating Conan to add CONAN_CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE to env_vars: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/4706

Comment: It seems you confuse **answers** and **comments**. Currently, there is the only *answer* provided by @BrandonDyer. My post and yours are *comments*, not answers. If you find a resolution for your problem, you may add your own answer ([self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)), and even accept it (green mark) as working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to get the functionality you're looking for with the `-D` flag.

I would try something like this: `cmake -D CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE=STATIC_LIBRARY`